# Convert two arrays to associative array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need to convert some arrays into associative array. I need the values to be saved together.

```
'days1' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string '30' (length=2)
      1 => string '90' (length=2)
      2 => string '50' (length=2)
      3 => string '50' (length=2)
      4 => string '5' (length=1)
  'price1' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string '5' (length=1)
      1 => string '10' (length=2)
      2 => string '12' (length=2)
      3 => string '13' (length=2)
      4 => string '1' (length=1)
  'days2' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '30' (length=2)
      1 => string '90' (length=2)
      2 => string '180' (length=3)
  'price2' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '6' (length=1)
      1 => string '7' (length=1)
      2 => string '10' (length=2)
```

So days1 needs to merge with price1 and create something like this

```
array(
 30 => 5,
 90 =>10,
 50 => 12,
 50 => 13,
 5 => 1
)
```

Comment: Your desired output is impossible because PHP does not permit duplicated keys on the same level.  Proof: https://3v4l.org/lKghm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `array_combine` -

```
array_combine ( array $keys , array $values ) -
```

More Info at : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Btw this is not multidimensional array, just associative.